# How to encode a proprietary asymmetric publickey in X509

Tags: java, encoding, certificate, x509, jce

I am working on a cryptographic library in Java that creates its own proprietary asymmetric cryptosystem (we have a valid reason for doing this that is too long to explain here). This asymmetric cryptosystem is an implementation of ElGamal. The library provides a mechanism for generating keypairs and for encrypting and decrypting data.

The public and private keys of this cryptosystem do not currently implement any interface (they have no connection with Key from java.security).

However we now have the requirement that we need to store an ElGamal public key inside an X509 certificate. To do this we plan on implementing the java.security.PublicKey interface in our proprietary public key, as this will allow us to pass our proprietary public key as a PublicKey (to allow it to be stored in a certificate).  However, implementing PublicKey means that we must now implement three new methods in our PublicKey, these are:

- public String getAlgorithm()
- public String getFormat()
- public byte[] getEncoded()

The getEncoded() method should return the public key encoded in some way. In keeping with convention, we would like to encode the data using X509 format.

We question is: how can the contents of an arbitrary object be encoded using this encoding format?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes What did you mean by "older cryptography"? Certain things can be considered old once some weakness is found in them, it happens sometimes with Hash functions, it happens sometimes with Operating Systems! But I only mentioned ElGamal which is a totally secure and respected system, albeit, not as widely used as RSA. But it does offer advantages over RSA, such as being homomorphic with regards to multiplication, allowing certain manipulations to be performed on ciphertexts, which the application took advantage of. I also mentioned X509, which is still a standard 5 years later!

Comment: Yes, I do know the advantages of ElGamal and Homomorphic encryption and I've actually used them myself. However, PKIX is a widely recognized system. RSA is commonly used for places that need encryption. In that case it makes little sense to define something that is recognized by nobody else, regardless if it is secure or not. That said, I've added an additional link in my answer, in case you want to set up a proprietary PKI, possibly including a few organizations that you'd want to communicate with.

Comment: That initial response was indeed too strong and too personal. It was not an attack on ElGamal either. I used "old" because everybody is using RSA now and that the attempts to use ElGamal in certificates have failed in the past; nothing more. And I indeed do not know your use case, so there is really nothing to grasp for me. Still, augmenting X.509 certificate specs and implementing ElGamal correctly is not for everybody, so I have placed a warning in my augmented answer, which I hope you do appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

X.509 specifies the format of a certificate. The public key itself is just one part of it. Within the X.509 data structure it is stored as a bit string (so basically raw binary data).

The `getEncoded` method typically returns the DER encoding of a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure which contains the algorithm encoded as an ASN.1 object identifier and the bits of the public key itself.

The [documentation of Key](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html) gives some more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The Java docs of key has some info, but not a lot. Do you know where I can find more info on this? I need to implement getEncoded(), therefore I guess that I need to create a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure, including the public key (somehow converted to a bit stream) and later encode this in DER. A step-by-step guide on this would be useful!

Comment: Well, the first step would be to allocate an object identifier for the algorithm since you said it is a proprietary one. Then, some basics about ASN.1 encodings are helpful, see for example http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html

Comment: thanks. One other question. Regarding the storing of a proprietary public key in ASN.1, are there any good libraries in Java for doing this? it seems to me that I have to produce a byte[] from my public key, according to the ASN.1 encoding structure defined in the description of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html. But I am not sure how to start creating such a structure in Java.

Comment: The structure is relatively simple. So I guess it will be easier to do it with some custom code rather than using a library or an ASN.1 compiler. However, you may want to search for "asn.1 java" and see if something fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Henry is of course correct, however stopping with SubjectPublicKeyInfo is a bit of a tricky thing, as SubjectPublicKeyInfo is little more than a definition of a container.

If you encode an ElGamal public key using the `getEncoded` specified by Bouncy Castle then you will get [this ASN.1 structure][1]:

```
SEQUENCE (2 elem)
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER: 1.3.14.7.2.1.1
    SEQUENCE (2 elem)
      INTEGER (2048 bit): 3231…
      INTEGER: 2
  BIT STRING (1 elem)
    INTEGER (2048 bit): 2072…
```

So that's a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` (first sequence) with an ElGamal algorithm identifier (and [ElGamal OID](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.14.7.2.1.1)), which in turn contains the large prime and generator (with value 2). Then comes the `BIT STRING`, which contains an `INTEGER` with the public key value.

Note that I find it exceedingly hard to find out if the above is specified anywhere. IOW seems to have been some workshop in which NIST was also involved.

[1]: http://lapo.it/asn1js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

---

EDIT: Upon looking again I found this [old internet draft by Peter Gutmann](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-rfced-info-pgutmann-00) (expired in 1998!) that tried to define ElGamal for X.509 certificates. That seems to be a good base for your ElGamal specific `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure. At first glance it looks like the same structure that Bouncy emits.

As indicated in the comments, that's fine if you want to setup your own PKI, but any other parties will have to agree with on the changes of the certificate and the precise implementation of ElGamal.